# Хранение данных из БД в JSON файлах

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, json

Доброго времени суток !

Я пишу сайт, и там есть список товаров. Мне пришла идея - на сервере загружать данные из mySQL в JSON файл, и на клиенте выгружать данные из JSON файла в список, используя angularJS.

Вопрос:

1. Актуальна ли такая идея?
2. Какие есть опасности в данном методе?
3. Что-то посоветуете ?
4. Или это бредовая идея ?

Заранее спасибо за ответы)

---

P.S.
Смущает меня только то, что опыта у меня не много, и я не знаю как правильно и лучше) Потому обращаюсь к Вам )

Comment: вопросы очень поверхностные, общие..

Comment: соглашусь, вопрос действительно слишком общий. описывайте задачу более подробно с указанием, почему вы думаете что так будет лучше, и в почему сомневаетесь.  Сам подход загрузки данных в т.ч. для списков через аякс естественно широко распространен, в зависимости от решаемой задачи. Единственное, что прямо в файл то не часто выгружают, обычно пхп код возвращает json-данные + они кешируются на стороне клиента/сервера.

Comment: для размышлений вам - Всегда ли показывается этот список. Если всегда, то какой смысл его куда то выносить. Тут имеет смысл закешировать результат запроса к БД. Второе в обратную сторону - вытаскивание данных на клиенте - лишний запрос к серверу. Взвешивайте плюсы и минусы в конкретной ситуации. Если вам просто ради интереса и практики - то сделайте да и все.

Comment: хотя в статику (в файл) тоже можно сохранять, вэб-сервер его отдает вообще сразу.